# Yii: set "url" of "label" to outside of baseurl

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

could you, please, advise,
['label' => 'Dashboard', 'url' => ['']],
how to set "url" to the url kind of "http://example.com"?
I mean how to set this to the url, which is outside of Yii baseurl.
thanks

Comment: Still it's require some explanation with example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple.
In this way you can

```
['label' => 'Dashboard', 'url' => 'http://example.com']
```